# node = node.next doesnt work at linked list

Tags: javascript, linked-list

Im doing remove function, that deletes node from it. Im trying to do recursive to work with any length. And now I stuck with one problem:

```
a = {value: 1, next: {value: 2, next: {value: 3, next: null}}}
let node = a.next;
node = node.next;
console.log(a)
```

Why its not rorking? It works only with `a.next = a.next.next;` instead of `node = node.next`. How to solve this?

Comment: *"It works only with ... how to solve this?"*: so you got it working, then why do you ask how to solve it?

Comment: It works with your solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to log the variable `node` instead of `a`, Since we mutate `node` and not `a`

```
a = {value: 1, next: {value: 2, next: {value: 3, next: null}}}
let node = a.next;
node = node.next;
console.log(node)
```

You can also mutate the `next` property inside `node` since It's pass by reference.

```
a = {value: 1, next: {value: 2, next: {value: 3, next: null}}}
let node = a.next;
node.next = node.next.next;
console.log(a)
```

Comment: There is no "pass by reference" here. That is a concept that only plays a role in function calls, and it isn't a thing in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you're reassigning the node variable, but not the next property of the original node.

```
a = {value: 1, next: {value: 2, next: {value: 3, next: null}}}
let node = a.next;
node.next = node.next.next;
console.log(a)
```